# Jquery to capture and output information from html form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having problems with this bit of code. For some reason it won't capture the radSize, and it's giving me problems. Any ideas?

The page is supposed to capture the values, then add the base and size together to output total.

```
  $(function() {
    $("#btnMessage").click(function() {
      var name = $("input[name=txtName]").val();
      var phone = $("input[name=txtPhone]").val();
      var basePizza = $("#cboBase").val();
      var size = $("input[name=radSize]").is(":checked").val;

      // alert(name +" "+ phone +" "+ basePizza +" "+ size);

      var message = "";

      var calculation = parseInt(basePizza) + parseInt(size);
      //test each value

      if (name == "")
        message += "--Enter a first name";

      if (phone == "")
        message += "\n--Provide a number";

      if (basePizza == "0")
        message += "\n--Pick Base Pizza";

      if (size == "")
        message += "\n--Pick a Size";

      else
        message += name + "," + " " + "Your total for the pizza will be " + "$" + calculation;

      alert(message);

      // $('#output').html(message);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line isn't really valid:

```
var size            = $("input[name=radSize]").is(":checked").val;
```

The `.is(":checked")` part is a [jQuery filtering utility](http://api.jquery.com/is/) that will return `true` or `false`.

Instead, you want to do something like this:

```
var size            = $("input[name='radName']:checked").val();
```

Assuming only one of the "radSize" checkboxes can be checked,  `$("input[name='radName']:checked")` will return the checked checkbox and `val()` will return its value.